# Plotar várias colunas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

Preciso plotar todas as colunas de uma tabela em relação à uma coluna específica.

Conjunto de dados:

```r
df <- read.table(
text = "c1 c2 c3  x
        2  4   5  0
        3  5   2  0
        6  7   8  0
        1  2   5  1
        2  5   6  1
        3  3   3  1", header = TRUE)
```

Preciso plotar os valores das colunas c1, c2 e c2 com os valores da coluna X de modo que eu perceba qual a correlação deles com os valores 0 e 1:

No momento estou tentando o seguinte, mas não está saindo o que preciso:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% gather("id", "value", 1:3) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x, id, color = x))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O segredo aqui está em entender o output da função `gather`. Vejamos ele em detalhes abaixo.

```r
df <- read.table(
    text = "c1 c2 c3  x
        2  4   5  0
        3  5   2  0
        6  7   8  0
        1  2   5  1
        2  5   6  1
        3  3   3  1", header = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% gather("id", "value", 1:3)
#>    x id value
#> 1  0 c1     2
#> 2  0 c1     3
#> 3  0 c1     6
#> 4  1 c1     1
#> 5  1 c1     2
#> 6  1 c1     3
#> 7  0 c2     4
#> 8  0 c2     5
#> 9  0 c2     7
#> 10 1 c2     2
#> 11 1 c2     5
#> 12 1 c2     3
#> 13 0 c3     5
#> 14 0 c3     2
#> 15 0 c3     8
#> 16 1 c3     5
#> 17 1 c3     6
#> 18 1 c3     3
```

Note que há 3 colunas. Usaremos `x` e `value` para tomarem os valores de `x` e `c1`, `c2` e `c3` do conjunto original, fazendo com que `id` seja o identificador de cada coluna no formato longo. Assim, temos o seguinte gráfico:

```r
df %>% gather("id", "value", 1:3) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = value, colour = id)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Note que não dá para perceber muita coisa em relação à correlação de `c1`, `c2` e `c3` com `x`, pois `x` só tem dois valores. Uma maneira de resolver isso é ajustando uma curva a cada valor de `id`. Neste caso, optei por uma regressão linear simples e a visualização melhorou um pouco.

```r
df %>% gather("id", "value", 1:3) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = value, colour = id)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Outra forma seria dividindo os `id` em painéis, para ao menos separar melhor os grupos de pontos e facilitar a visualização de tendências.

```r
df %>% gather("id", "value", 1:3) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = value)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ id)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Vou tentar aqui. Vlw